# Jquery treeview via asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery

How can I populate a jQuery Treeview via asp.net?

And then afterwards populate access to Text and Value of selected node Treeview at clientside?

Comment: What jquery treeview are you using?

Comment: it doesn't matter,any jquery treeview that can populate from asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JsTree](https://www.jstree.com/) is a great plugin to use to populate tree views.  It's simple and uses jQuery. For more information on how to get it working with asp, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34071334/4896260). I was able to populate the treeviews using `HTMLGenericControls` and ASP `Repeater`.